# Replacing parts of expressions in Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm using regex find and replace feature in Sublime Text 3, searching for expressions of the form `(\cref{exNUMBER})` or `(\cref{exNUMBERLETTER})` For example:

```
(\cref{ex1})
(\cref{ex1a})
```

The following regex finds these expressions just fine:

```
\(\\cref\{ex(\d|\d\l)\}\)
```

What I'm struggling with is how to replace these same expressions with expressions of the form `\eqref{exNUMBER}` or `\eqref{exNUMBERLETTER}`. For example, the above examples would produce:

```
\eqref{ex1}
\eqref{ex1a}
```

I've tried doing a roughly parallel construction, `\\eqref\{ex(\d|\d\l)\}`, but all that produces when I replace is the following: `\eqref{ex(d|d)}`.

What is the correct way to use regex wildcards while replacing in Sublime Text 3 so that I can replace `(\cref{exNUMBER})` or `(\cref{exNUMBERLETTER})`, with `\eqref{exNUMBER}` or `\eqref{exNUMBERLETTER}` (respectively)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture what you want to keep in a group (so you can put it back in the replace):

```
\(\\c(ref\{ex(\d|\d\l)\})\)
     ^                  ^
```

Markers indicate brackets added to capture stuff you want to keep as a group (group 1).

And replace matches with:

```
\eq\1
```

The `\1` is a *back reference* to group 1 - it outputs what was captured in the match.

Comment: With the minor modification of adding "\\" to the beginning of the replace line (`\\eq\1`) in order to retain the backslash before "eq", this works great.

Answer (score 2):

Bohemian's answer is perfect and should be the accepted answer. I am just adding something simpler as well, since w/ the complexity of the OP's regular expression I found it a bit hard to follow. For a simpler case, imagine we had a text file containing:

```
345
3234
23423
```

which we wanted to convert to:

```
{ value: 345 }
{ value: 3234 }
{ value: 23423 }
```

The correct syntax for the find/replace would be:

- **Find**: `(\d+)`
- **Replace**: `{ value: \1 }`

Bohemian's answer explains the logic behind this really clearly, just with a lot more slashes :).